# Search/replace only in first line of the document

Tags: macros, notepad++

How to create a search replace rule that will search only in the first line of the content in Notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use regular expression search in Notpad++, the following expression will pick the first line:

```
[^\n]+\.
```

To search for a particular word in the first sentence, you could use something like:

[^\n]*apple[^\n]*

Supposing your text was:

> This is the new updated document for UI design from engineering side.
>   Please take a look and see if you have any question or suggestion
>   before I send to a bigger group.

Supposing you wanted to replace document with papyrus. Then you could open Notepad++ > Find > Search Mode > Regular Expression.

Find what:

```
([^\n]*)(document)([^\n]*).*
```

Replace with:

```
\1papyrus\3
```

This would replace document with papyrus in the first line only if you click Replace instead of Replace All

Comment: Your regex is matching everything until the first `.` (including the `.`) but not the first line.

Comment: I assumed by line you meant sentence. If you want line, you could use:

([^\n]+)(document)([^\n]+\n)

Comment: I am very sure when Pentium10 says "line" he means "line" and not "sentence".

Comment: Line is a line that is numbered by notepad++ not a sentence.